# Android - Espresso tests code coverage for multi module project

Tags: android, sonarqube, code-coverage, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have project structure like:

**module-app**

```
androidTest //Espresso tests covers classes from login and registration
main //Contains UI and business logic
test
```

**module-login**

```
androidTest //No tests written
main //Contains UI and business logic
test //Only unit tests
```

**module-registration**

```
androidTest //No tests written
main //Contains UI and business logic
test
```

Issue: I have above like android project structure and able to generate jacoco code coverage report and it is available to sonar dashboard. Issue I am facing with the espresso tests which only shows code coverage for module-app but not for other modules. Espresso tests are running for usecase flow like registration and then login and call classes from other two modules but the coverage for other two modules are 0% always.

- I would like to understand how espresso generates code coverage is it similar like unit tests where same package and class for which unit tests are written?
- How can I see line by line coverage from the code written in espresso tests? What all classes these tests are covering from whole project src.
- Should I write the espresso test in other modules as well ? Not sure it will show the coverage.
- Please suggest any missing config for the espresso code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Jacoco and sonar will not show the coverage if no tests are present in androidTest for any particular module. Once the tests are present in in androidTest it will start showing the coverage data to sonar dashboard.